# Issue with repository Powerdesinger 16.1

Tags: repository

I work with Power Designer 16.1 and I believe I have an issue with the repository. Most of time I do checkIn of models without any problems.
But sometimes I lost completely the model from repository so I am obliged to do check in of my last local version, what makes me lose all the historical works of colleague.

After some analysis (and I may be wrong) I think that the problem occurred when someone try to do check-in and did not finalize the work ( took more time that needed) and someone else in the same time try to do check. The Models will disappears from repository confusion of the path.

If someone already had this problem and could help please?